# How to enforce stricter typing on Maps and Sets in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

If I create a map like so: ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDMBTA7jAsgQwA4AUAlANwCwAUKJLAJ5LwB0A5qlAQEQBmIIHplWoygALAJYQAIiFQQwUAKJwJ7UkA))

```js
const x = new Map();
const y = x.get("foo");
y.thisDoesntExist();
```

I'd expect to get an error on the last line (at least in strict mode), because I've never specified what the key and value types of `new Map` should be. Instead the type of the map is `Map<any, any>` and so I don't get any warnings. The same happens with `Set<any>`.

I'm in the process of porting a JavaScript project so cases like these are all over the place and it's hard to tell where types are missing.

Is there a way to configure typescript so that it warns me when I try to instantiate Sets and Maps without generics? Or at least make the generics default to `Set<unknown>`?

Comment: I'd expect it to warn under `noImplicitAny` but it doesn't seem to. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13609

Comment: @AlekseyL. Ah thanks! I feel like I've been looking everywhere for an issue like this but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I think the problem is that `MapConstructor` explicitly specifies ` new(): Map<any, any>;`

Comment: You could use declaration merging and override `MapConstructor` interface. I can add an answer if that works for you. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJwA4GED2IDOYUArgmDlMgN4CwAUMo8iBAO4AUAlAFxqYA8xEAGsQOViAA0yIaPEgAfAG56AX3r0EeQsgAeyALzM2fDFxV0tBMMgCehvQDoA5hDDsARDBw4PnJcgA9IF2vLJiEvS2jmAAFsD4ACI4EPjgAKK6Ce7+GnSa2ja6AIwOLKym-IRQoM7S1bUK5gXWdqVGJS5unt6+-kEhtsW8DSDOyAA+MiAAJhAwoBAzUcUx8UkpaWCZ2eZAA

Comment: Ah yes this is what I was looking for! Unfortunately I don't think I'll be able to use it though. I'm mostly using types in JSDoc and I just found out calling constructors with generics is not supported in JSDoc :( https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38876

Comment: @AlekseyL. Feel free to write up an answer though, I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameterless `Map` [constructor](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/6c8c829148b42dbc37704c1841f8d6eb6445ac6b/src/lib/es2015.collection.d.ts#L11-L15) has `Map<any, any>` return type:

```
interface MapConstructor {
    new(): Map<any, any>;
    // ...
}
```

Hence the `noImplicitAny` won't help here (the type is explicit  )

What can be done is overriding it ([declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)) with `Map<unknown, unknown>`:

```
interface MapConstructor {
    new(): Map<unknown, unknown>;
}
```

Now `y.thisDoesntExist();` will be reported as error.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJwA4GED2IDOYUArgmDlMgN4CwAUMo8iBAO4AUAlAFxqYA8xEAGsQOViAA0yIaPEgAfAG56AX3r0EeQsgAeyALzM2fDFxV0tBMMgCehvQDoA5hDDsARDBw4PnJcgA9IF2vLJiEvS2jmAAFsD4ACI4EPjgAKK6Ce7%20GnSa2ja6AIwOLKym-IRQoM7S1bUK5gXWdqVGJS5unt6%20-kEhtsW8DSDOyAA%20MiAAJhAwoBAzUcUx8UkpaWCZ2c35%201Y6%20GUmAMrd-cHI%20LznYIIiEYpAA)

---

The `Set` behaves differently, because its constructor is defined as:

```
new <T = any>(values?: readonly T[] | null): Set<T>;
```

So if the generic type and values are not provided - the type will be `unknown`:

```
const s = new Set(); // s: Set<unknown>
```

Comment: With some changes I managed to get it to work for jsdoc as well :)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know JS had a different defaults

Comment: Yeah me neither, found out about it because of this.

Answer (score 1):

**update (June 28, 2022)**

It seems like simply using `never` instead of `unknown` is enough to make types strict when using JavaScript + JSDoc. Not sure why I had to jump through so many hoops earlier, but now I'm just using.

```
interface SetConstructor {
    new(): Set<never>;
}

interface MapConstructor {
    new(): Map<never, never>;
}
```

---

**Old answer**

To make this work with ts in js using JSDoc, you can add the following in a new `.d.ts`

```
interface MapConstructor extends Omit<MapConstructor, 'new'> {
    new<K = unknown, V = unknown>(entries?: readonly (readonly [K, V])[] | null): Map<K, V>;
}

interface SetConstructor {
    new <T = unknown>(values?: readonly T[] | null): Set<T>;
}
```

In JavaScript, generics default to `any` when not set ([#14907](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/14907)), so you have to explicitly set their defaults to `unknown`. Therefore an empty constructor doesn't work when using JavaScript.

`MapConstructor` has an empty `new(): Map<any, any>` entry in `lib.es2015.collection.d.ts`. So in order to remove this we use `Omit<MapConstructor, 'new'>`. Then we can specify the same constructor that already exists, except with explicit `unknown` as defaults.

`SetConstructor` doesn't have an empty `new()` entry, but it does have `new <T = any>`, so we'll have to override this with `unknown` as well.